# checkbox persists after a row is deleted from a table

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector

I have built a checkbox feature on a table using this page:

http://www.carrotcoded.com/2012/12/02/uibutton-within-uitableviewcell-checkbox/

This works fine, and I can check and uncheck boxes.    Then I clear all of them with the delegate that was created, "clearCheckedItems" .   This method has a loop to add unchecked items to a new Glist, and build an array of deleted indices.

Approach 0, "beginUpdates" Method:
Passed an indice list to the removeRows method, but it crashes due
to a "bad selector", NSLog shown at bottom.

Approach 1, "reloadView" Method:
Removes checked rows, does not crash, but leaves a persistent "checked" checkbox graphic that
is a "ghost", it does not indicate the state of that table cell any more.

```
 ////////////////  start of code //////////////////////////
 - (IBAction)clearCheckedItems:(id)sender {
 groceryList *myGroceryList  = [ groceryList sharedSingleton ];
 gList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
 gList = myGroceryList.myGroceryListS ;

int i;
NSMutableArray *checkedOffGlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
NSMutableArray *removedIndexArray = [[ NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
for ( i=0 ; i < sizeOfList ; i++) {
    groceryItem *current = [ gList  objectAtIndex:i  ];
    if ( current.bought == (bool )NO  ) {
        [ checkedOffGlist addObject:current ] ;
    }  else {
        [ removedIndexArray addObject:[ NSNumber numberWithInt:i ] ] ;
    }
}

myGroceryList.myGroceryListS = checkedOffGlist   ;

//* update the table, clear all the check boxes *//
NSString *whichTableUpdate = @"beginUpdates";
  //* beginUpdates method *//
if  ( [whichTableUpdate isEqualToString:@"beginUpdates" ]) {    
    [ self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [ self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
          [NSArray arrayWithObject:removedIndexArray ]         
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic ];
    [ self.tableView endUpdates];
    // *** fails with message below *** //
} else {
    //* reloadView method *//       
    [ self.tableView reloadData   ];
    // *** does not crash, but leaves behind a persistent "checked" box icon.
}


}
```

2013-06-18 09:32:32.843 groceryList[5730:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x717cb30'
*** First throw call stack:

..cb30 is the pointer to the list of removed indexes, "removedIndexArray".

SO….how do I get the the right index list to the row remover, or am I running the row removal method incorrectly?

Comment: The persistant checkbox icon is because of the reusableCells.  If you are using reusableCells then you need to reset them to "stock", as it were, every time you use it for a different cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The persistant checkbox icon is because of the reusableCells.  If you are using reusableCells then you need to reset them to "stock" as it were every time you use it for a different cell.

As for the crashing, you are trying to delete indexPaths by using integers.  And indexPath is a path (section and row).  Where you are adding the int, add a newly created index path instead (I'm assuming there is only one section, so it would be section 0 row i).  If you need code examples for all of this let me know.

Comment: The indexPath idea fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and accurate response.